# Why does Tkinter won't get my changed value?

Tags: python, tkinter

After multiples researches I can't success to get the modified user input of my Tinter Entry

```
def mail(value):
    print(value)    

value = StringVar() 
value.set("Default text")
entree = Entry(fenetre, textvariable=value, validate="key", width=30)
entree.pack()
value = value.get()
bouton1=Button(fenetre, text="Validate", command=lambda: mail(value))
bouton1.pack()
```

When I launch my program, and when I modify the text of the Entry, and when I click on validate, the text value has no changed, why ?
Even if I change the label of the Entry, when I click on validate, it print me always "Default Text"

Answer (score 3):

You are almost immediately reassigning a new value to the `value` reference. First you do `value = StringVar()`, and then a few lines later you do `value = value.get()`. At that point, `value` is no longer a `StringVar`; it's just a string. Remove that second assignment, and change the line with the `Button` to retrieve the value itself:

```
bouton1 = Button(fenetre, text="Validate", command=lambda: mail(value.get()))
```